# Why isn't my hidden DIV being displayed at all?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a form that has to redirect the user (part of Salesforce's redirect requirement). I would like to keep the user on the page, so the redirect link is the same page with "?submitted=1" added to it. I have tried so many different scripts found online to check for the submitted url, then change the div from none to block. It does not work and I'm not sure why. Here is the latest code I have, but keep in mind, I have been searching and trying all sorts of answers from here and around the web, so I may have already tried something else.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="savingsSuccess">
    <div id="alertSuccess" class="alert alert-success">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><strong>Your inputs have been sent to our team, we will send your savings estimate to email</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is here:

```
#alertSuccess {
    display: none;
}
```

My script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (/submitted/.test(window.location.href)) {
      document.getElementByID('alertSuccess').style.display = 'block';
   }
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your script tag before or after your div tag? If it before your JavaScript is being run before the div exists...

Comment: Your regular expression test with the href looks good. When the script enters the if statement, do you know if `#alertSuccess` exists? I would start there.

Comment: Yes, the script is after the div. However, I was using `getElementByID` and not `getElementById`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misspelling the method `getElementById`, must be `Id` instead of `ID`.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) are the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your script.

Firstly: Id not ID, and just to make things a bit less hackish, I went ahead and split/substringed the URL

HTML:

```
<div id="savingsSuccess">
    <div id="alertSuccess" class="alert alert-success">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><strong>Your inputs have been sent to our team, we will send your savings estimate to email</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS is here:

```
#alertSuccess {
    display: none;
}
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("?"),window.location.href.length-1).split("&").indexOf("submitted=1")==-1) {
      document.getElementById('alertSuccess').style.display = 'block';
   }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hackish"? The code you see, I found in one of the search results I found on here.

Comment: What if the file path contains the word "submitted"?

Comment: It's a minor change, but it's an option